# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "guestbooks" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I continue to get this error message in my Papertrail logs when I try to access my URL /guestbooks.

This route works great on localhost, but not on Heroku. Are my rails naming conventions off? I think they are right, but I could be mistaken.

I tried running `rake db:rest`, I then tried running `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`, which showed that I was getting errors in my migration files, so I deleted them and then ran the command again and no longer received the migration files error from PG.

I tried committing my changes and running `heroku run rake db:migrate`, but my error persisted. Below are my MVC and routes.

```
    class GuestbooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_page

    def index
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new
    end

    def create
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new(guestbook_params)

        if @guestbook.save
            flash.now[:notice] = "Thanks for taking the time to write us! We greatly appreciate it!"
            render :index
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = "Your message failed to post, please try again"
            render :index
        end
    end

    private

    def load_page
        @guestbooks = Guestbook.page(params[:page])
    end

    def guestbook_params
        params.require(:guestbook).permit(:name, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

My schema

```
  create_table "guestbooks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My model

```
class Guestbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    paginates_per 5
end
```

Comment: rake db:drop db:create db:migrate won't work on Heroku, you will need to do `heroku pg:reset` before you then do `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: I was looking at that, but couldn't find the exact syntax. I have to specificy a particular database. Would it be heroku pg:reset, :guestbooks  ? @JohnBeynon

Comment: no `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` <- exactly that - it will reset the whole DB to nothing.

Comment: @JohnBeynon thanks for your answer, turns out that didn't solve my issue. Ran that and then the migration task and it still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn’t have any migrations (only schema.rb). You can remove all migrations if you want, but if you do, you need to run rake db:setup to use schema.rb to setup the database (rake db:reset will only look for migrations).